# FastAPI POST Pydantic method unit testing redirecting status_code 307 instead of 200

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, http-post, fastapi

I have a test case where I am testing a `POST` service using `pytest` hosted with `FastAPI` Uvicorn. However the response is getting responded with status code `307`. But this doesn't happen on actual webservice is tested through a browser or `curl`. What is happening here?

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from src.main import app
import json

client = TestClient(app)

def test_get_confidence_ws():
    data = {
        "acc_id": 1234567801,
        "remoteIp": "127.255.255.255",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"
    }
    response = client.post("/confidence", json=json.dumps(data))
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Test response

```
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 307 == 200
E        +  where 307 = <Response [307]>.status_code
```

EDIT:

Actual endpoint that is tested:

```
@app.post("/confidence/")
def get_confidence(json: LoginClassifierSchema):
    ...
    response = {
           "key" : "value"
        }
    return response
```

Comment: Is your endpoint defined as `/confidence/` and not `/confidence`? Since you didn't include the FastAPI code, it's hard to say - but that's usually the reason.

Comment: Yes. However if I drop the `/` in the end, the response code changes to `422`

Comment: Added the actual endpoint @MatsLindh

Comment: @MatsLindh pointed out the reason for the 307 - if you define the endpoint with trailing slash and try to POST to it without slash, you will get 307 with Location: header. The 422 is probably due to your POST data not validating with the `LoginClassifierSchema` model.

Comment: The body of the 422 error response will contain the error message telling you exactly which required value is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MatsLindh and @Vaizki for your responses. The problem was indeed with `/` and `Validation`. I will explain in detail so as this benefits the community.

1>If you are getting redirected to 307 this is indeed you have an extra '/' in the endpoint.

2>If you are getting `422` it is most likely a parsing issue. In my case I was using `pydantic` and though pydantic models are dictionary like, they are not dictionaries. Therefore to get the exact keys you need to convert the data at endpoint to a dictionary by calling `data.dict()`. eg.,

```
@app.post("/confidence")
def get_confidence(data: LoginClassifierSchema):
     data = data.dict()
     ...
     ...
     return JSONResponse({"key":"val"}, status_code=200)
```

In order to understand at an early stage it is a validation issue, add a *exception handler* method to your app class with endpoints.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
        """
        This catches the schema validation error made during the call
        """
        validation_err = {"exception": "RequestValidationError: unable to parse input, " + str(exc)}
        return JSONResponse(validation_err, status_code=400)
```